# Building a Node app should I use App Engine or Google Cloud Run?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am creating a Node app it has express, swagger and Agenda for running scheduled Jobs.
What is the best way to deploy it in GCP. Should I use App Engine or Cloud run.

From what I understand in Cloud Run it will run in a container like docker for App Engine it will just use my application and host it. Please enlighten me what should I do?

Cheers,
Cam

Answer (score 33, accepted):

App Engine is a Platform-as-a-Service. It means that you simply deploy your code, and the platform does everything else for you. For example, if your app becomes very successful, App Engine will automatically create more instances to handle the increased volume.

It auto scales from 0 to unlimited instances (It uses GCE underneath). It comes with 2 flavors Standard Environment and Flexible Environment.
Standard Environment is really fast, scales down to 0 instances when no-one is using your app, scales up and down in seconds and has dedicated Google services and libraries for caching, authentication etc. The caveat with Standard environment is that it is very restrictive since it runs in a sandbox. The recent additions are Node.js (8.x) and Python 3.x.
Flexible Environment is more open as it allows you to use custom runtimes as it uses docker containers. Thus if your runtime is not available in the provided runtimes, you can always create your own dockerfile for the execution environment. The caveat with it is, it requires having at least 1 instance running, even if no-one is using your app, plus the scaling up and down requires a few minutes.

[Read more about App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine)

App Engine is for deploying code, Cloud Run for deploying containers, and containers are today’s requirements.Cloud Run runs containers, so for each release you have to build a container and push it to GCP.

Cloud Run, App Engine Flexible and Newer runtimes of App Engine Standard are designed for portability (you can use open-source libraries or standard libraries and not just Google Libraries). Cloud Run and App Engine Flexible allow for custom runtimes.

Cloud Run gives you the freedom to expand your infrastructure into hybrid and multi-cloud environments.

[Read more about Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/overview/what-is-cloud-run)

**Differences you should consider:**

- For a low-traffic application, Cloud Run or App Engine Standard which is set to automatic scaling are both cheaper than App Engine Standard which is set to manual/basic scaling or App Engine Flexible. Cloud Run only runs when it is serving requests. App Engine which is set to automatic scaling shuts down when it is not serving requests. This means for both types, you're not using resources when your application is not running and Google only bills you for resources that you consume. In addition, App Engine Standard provides a free daily quota of resources so you're only billed for consuming resources above the free quota. App Engine Flexible or App Engine Standard set to manual/basic scaling must have at least 1 instance running continuously, which means they run for a full month which in turn means you're going to pay more.
- App Engine responds on average 56 ms faster than Cloud Run. The huge
  caveat here is that these times vary widely between runs, sometimes
  tripling or quadrupling The total request size from Cloud Run was
  larger because it doesn’t gzip files by default. The big difference
  between the two services is that Cloud Run doesn’t run your container
  unless it’s getting requests. When a request comes in, it does
  things:   [i] boots up the container [ii] serves the request [iii]
  shuts down the container   Of course, you also save a lot of money
  doing it this way, so the tradeoff here is whether you care more
  about optimizing your speed or your cost.
- AppEngine can only be deployed to a single region. If you want an
  AppEngine app to be multi-regional then you need one project per
  region. Cloud run allows you to deploy a service to every region
  within a single project making your API truly global, all within a
  single project
- Cloud Run also allows you to set up a static IP address, something
  you cannot get with AppEngine. This is helpful for situations where
  you need to relay mail or connect to some other service that
  restricts access by IP address. Also AppEngine still has some things
  Cloud Run doesn't (like Identity Aware Proxy) have.
- The docker image support in Cloud Run is also more versatile than
  what you get from AppEngine Standard, and Cloud Run has more robust
  options to choose from (more ram, cpu, etc).

---

---

[1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine)https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart
[2](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/overview/what-is-cloud-run)https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-nodejs-service

Comment: App Engine Flex & the newer runtimes for App Engine Standard were specifically marketed for portability of code. The newer runtimes of GAE standard did not initially include bundled APIs like the older runtimes and Google said this was to remove lock-in and make for code portability. Even now, Google documentation advises to use Cloud Libraries instead of Bundled APIs to make your code portable

Comment: For App Engine Standard - you only pay for the time your instance was up. If you set your instance to be automatically managed, it means your instance goes down when it is not serving traffic and so you do not pay for that period. App Engine also gives you a free daily quota of resources and so you only pay for any extra resources outside of the free quota that you consume.

Comment: Cloud Run also allows [deploying code](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying-source-code) (deploy from source), for those who don't want to manage/build their own containers.  Cloud Run just provides the option to use a custom container (in the same way App Engine Flex does), but you can deploy source (for supported languages), if you prefer, which is then built using buildpacks.

Comment: My understanding is in Cloud Run if there are no requests or traffic the instance is shutdown. Does this mean for background processes like scheduled tasks it is better to use App Engine?

Comment: Cloud Run instance go down **ONLY** when it is done processing the request. E.g. if you load a url which triggers code that opens a website, scrapes information, cleans it and dumps it in a DB, then the Cloud Run instance goes down **ONLY** when everything is done (it has dumped the data in the DB). Both Cloud Run & App Engine have timeouts (the request must return a response within that period). I believe it is 60 minutes for Cloud Run. GAE Standard is 1 - 10 minutes for automatic scaling, up to 24 hours for basic scaling, 60 minutes for Flexible.

Answer (score 0):

**Google App Engine:** 
App Engine provides a fully managed platform-as-a-service (PaaS) environment.
It offers automatic scaling, load balancing, and other infrastructure management tasks out of the box.

**Google Cloud Run:** 
Cloud Run is a serverless container platform that runs stateless containers on demand.
It provides a more flexible and customizable environment compared to App Engine.
You can deploy your Django app as a containerized application using Docker.
Cost efficient than App Engine